# Use characteristic equation to solve differential equation.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm reading a book on scientific computing and at one point the reader is supposed to look for the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions $u\neq 0$, such that $$-\dfrac{d^2u(x)}{dx^2} = \lambda u(x),$$ supplied with homogeneous Dirichlet or Neumann boundary conditions. To solve this one-dimensional system, the reader is supposed to use the characteristic equation $r^2 + \lambda = 0$.

The results are then given to be as follows:

- in case of Dirichlet boundary conditions $$u^{[k]}(x) = \sin(k\pi x), \text{ corresponding to } \lambda_k = k^2\pi^2\text{ for }k\in\mathbb{N},k\neq 0.$$
- in case of Neumann boundary conditions $$u^{[k]}(x) = \cos(k\pi x)\text{ corresponding to }\lambda_k = k^2\pi^2 \text{ for } k\in\mathbb{N}.$$

**My questions:**

- Why do we get these different results for the Dirichlet boundary conditions and Neumann conditions?
- What does the notation $u^{[k]}(x)$ mean?

Comment: I think the $k$ in $u^{[k]}$ is just an index. it indicates that there are independent solutions for each $k\in\mathbb{N}.$

Comment: I think $u^{[k]}(x)$ denotes the $k^{\text{th}}$ eigenfunction.

Answer (score 0):

The issue about the notation is addressed in the comments.

Regarding the boundary conditions, if the interval is $[0,1]$, then  the two cases are: $$(1)~~~u(0)=0,~~u(1)=0\qquad\text{Dirichlet}\\(2)~~~u'(0)=0,~~u'(1)=0\qquad\text{Neumann}$$In either case, for $\lambda>0$ the general solution to the differential equation is $u(x)=c_1\cos(\alpha x)+c_2\sin(\alpha x)$ where $\lambda=\alpha^2$. In case $(1)$, we necessarily get $c_1=0$. In case $(2)$, we necessarily get $c_2=0$. I leave it to you to see why $\alpha=k\pi$. When $\lambda=0$ we only get solutions in case $(2)$, which is why $k=0$ is possible only in case $(2)$. When $\lambda<0$ the general solution to the differential equation is $u(x)=c_1\cosh(\alpha x)+c_2\sinh(\alpha x)$ where $\lambda=-\alpha^2$. In both cases $(1)$ and $(2)$ we must have $c_1=c_2=0$, so there are no solutions in either case for $\lambda<0$.